# How relate doping concentration and electron concentration?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Say I have Si with the donar doping concentration $N_D=10^{14}  \text{cm}^{-3}$ and a temperature $T$.

How can I relate the donar doping concentration to the electron concentration?

I know the following equations, however they don't include $N_D$.

\begin{align}
n_0&=N_C\exp\bigg(\frac{E_f-E_c}{k_BT}\bigg)= 
n_i\exp\bigg(\frac{E_f-E_i}{k_BT}\bigg)\\
p_0&=N_v\exp\bigg(\frac{E_v-E_f}{k_BT}\bigg)= 
n_i\exp\bigg(\frac{E_i-E_f}{k_BT}\bigg)
\end{align}

Comment: Well, somewhere in the next section of your book you do have equations including $N_{D}$ in them.

Comment: You would need the binding energy. If that is not given, you assume that all donor atoms are ionized.